# Start custom script after wifi interface comes online

Tags: wifi

In a debian build, I have a custom `init.d` script. I've also modified my `network` so that the connection to the WiFi is done in the background.

How can I start my custom script, say `custom.sh` during boot up but have it actually run as soon as the network is brought up and connected?

Currently, I was thinking of looping every x seconds, and everytime check to see if the network is up. Once is it up, then you jump out of the loop.

Comment: Add `After=network.target` and `Wants=network.target` to the service file (if you are using systemd)...

Comment: I don't think that will guarantee it runs "as soon as", just "afterward", but hopefully good enough.   If you are using a sysvinit debian there's a similar mechanism there, see `/etc/init.d/README`.  I'm not sure if the latter can be done on the basis of success though.

Comment: can you add it in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, all methods to start and stop network connections run scripts under `/etc/network`. This is documented in the [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5) man page. It is part of the ifupdown package, but the scripts are executed even if the interface is brought up or down by frameworks such as NetworkManager rather than by the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands.

So put your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`. Make sure that it includes a check that the interface you wanted is up — in particular, you don't want your script to be executed as soon as the loopback interface goes up. You can check the name of the interface with the `IFACE` environment variable, either directly or by calling commands like `ifconfig`, `route` or `ip` to check its characteristics (IP address, gateway, …). Alternatively, you might check something independently of the interface, e.g. test that some host is reachable.

Note that scripts are executed in lexicographic order. If your script requires some other functionality (e.g. DNS) to be available, make sure that it comes later than the script that sets up this functionality.

Comment: I don't think that it would work as WLAN interface is up BEFORE being connected to network.